# Get Order Info Using SOAP API

Tags: magento-1.8, api, soap, sales-order

I am trying to make a simple API call to get some information on an Order. The reason I am trying with SOAP is because a similar API request is returning empty values for some sales attributes so I am trying to see if I get a different result using SOAP but I keep getting

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function salesOrderInfo() on a non-object in
```

I've followed the information on the Magento WIKI

[Here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/sales/salesOrder/sales_order.info.html)

But I keep getting this error, I've placed this file in the root of my Magento installation:

orderinfo.php

```
<?php

    $proxy = new SoapClient('http://www.mydomain.com/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1');

    $session = $proxy->login('user', 'password'); // connect to the API

    $result = $client->salesOrderInfo($session, '100000064');
    var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Just making sure. You did set up an api user/role correct?

Comment: @StevenLynn Yes My API User And Role is setup but I keep getting this error...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple error. You are using the wrong variable in SalesOrderInfo.

Your current code

Notice: That you set the session Id to $session, but then use $sessionId in salesOrderInfo.

```
<?php

$proxy = new SoapClient('http://www.mydomain.com/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1');

$session = $proxy->login('user', 'password'); // connect to the API

$result = $client->salesOrderInfo($sessionId, '100000064');
var_dump($result);
```

Edit: Another error. $client should be $proxy

Try the following code. This worked for me! Just add your url, and api username and password.

```
<?php

 $proxy = new SoapClient('http://www.mydomain.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl'); 

 $session = $proxy->login('user', 'password'); 

 $result = $proxy->salesOrderInfo($session, '100000064');

 var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I wish it were that simple :D I've been trying for hours... I'm thinking that I may need to add an include into the file to get access to the `salesOrderInfo` method or summick

Comment: Did you try that code?

Comment: There is no include you have to add to the file.

Comment: @SteveLynn Yes I sure did!

Comment: Just to clarify you used the bottom section? I am having a hard to believing it didn't work. Do you have soap installed on your server?

Comment: :D Just thinking out loud!! Absolutely, I'll update the post now...

Comment: Do you notice the differences between the two code sections I posted? You just tried to edit it to the same as the top one. The bottom one is the correct code.

Comment: Sorry, I posted the wrong code...

Comment: I updated my code once more. Try it and let me know if it works.