# Get shipments by order number in Magento 1.9 API

Tags: magento-1.9, api, collection, soap-api-v2

I am trying to get the list of shipments for a given order via the API (I use the SOAP API but I don't think it matters).

I don't have the order ID but the 9-digit number (the increment_id from the sales_flat_order table).

I can see the following code in the API method I am trying to call:

```
    /**
     * Retrieve shipments by filters
     *
     * @param null|object|array $filters
     * @return array
     */
    public function items($filters = null)
    {
        $shipments = array();

        $shipmentCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_shipment_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('increment_id')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('total_qty')
            ->joinAttribute('shipping_firstname', 'order_address/firstname', 'shipping_address_id', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('shipping_lastname', 'order_address/lastname', 'shipping_address_id', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('order_increment_id', 'order/increment_id', 'order_id', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('order_created_at', 'order/created_at', 'order_id', null, 'left');

        $apiHelper = Mage::helper('api');
        $filters = $apiHelper->parseFilters($filters, $this->_attributesMap['shipment']);
        foreach ($filters as $field => $value) {
            $shipmentCollection->addFieldToFilter($field, $value);
        }

        ...
        return $shipments;
    }
```

From: Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Shipment/Api.php (slightly edited for brevity).

I don't fully understand the syntax of this query but it seems like a join is made with the orders table, and then filters are added from the filters API parameter.

I have tried to call this API this way (calling from a C# program):

```
var shipments = Client.SalesOrderShipmentList(sessionId, new Filters
{
    filter = new AssociativeEntity[]
    {
        new AssociativeEntity
        {
            key = "order_increment_id",
            value = "000000006"
        }
    }
});
```

I am getting the following error:

> 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'order_increment_id' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT `main_table`.`increment_id`, `main_table`.`created_at`, `main_table`.`total_qty` FROM `sales_flat_shipment` AS `main_table` WHERE (`order_increment_id` = '000000006')'

It seems that the join isn't being translated to SQL.
I have tried several things like prefixing the column name with the orders table name, to no avail.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried doing `echo $shipmentCollection->getSelectSql(true);` to debug the SQL it generates? You can this in various places in the `Api.php`-file. As a workaround, you could do another call before the one above and get the order_id by increment_id; then use this for filtering shipments.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I can't seem to echo anything since it's an API (sorry I'm not a PHP dev). But I would guess the SQL would be the same as included in the error message? I am open to the work around but unfortunately I couldn't find an API that would give me the order_id from the increment_id.

Comment: I think it's quite easy in M2, and your client should update anyway :D M1 is EOL since June. Doesn't salesOrderInfo give you the entity_id? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/32215/get-order-info-using-soap-api, https://csharp.hotexamples.com/de/examples/-/MagentoService/salesOrderInfo/php-magentoservice-salesorderinfo-method-examples.html

Comment: Can't believe I missed it! I did look at that API but somehow did not find the entity_id the first time around. I will use that, thank you!

Comment: Nice. I added an answer so this question can be marked as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I can't help with the actual problem, I suggest to use a workaround:

Use 2 API-requests to first get the order's `entity_id`, and get shipment info with the second request.

The API-method to use here is `salesOrderInfo` as, for example, described here:

- [Get Order Info Using SOAP API](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/32215/get-order-info-using-soap-api)
- https://csharp.hotexamples.com/de/examples/-/MagentoService/salesOrderInfo/php-magentoservice-salesorderinfo-method-examples.html